# Язык или диалект?

Tags: лингвистика

Хотелось бы все же услышать неусложненный ответ на вопрос, по каким признакам можно считать язык (например, современный украинский) полноценным состоявшимся языком, а не одним из диалектов (наряду с русским, русинским, белорусским) общерусского "койне", каким было еще 200-300 лет назад великорусское наречие, точнее, его письменный, литературный и бюрократический вариант. Знакомство с разными архивными источниками показывает, что, по крайней мере, во времена Хмельницкого и даже Филиппа Орлика разница в лексике документов Великороссии и будущей Украины совершенно малозначительна.

Comment: А в интернете общаются на украинской мове? Сколько человек?

Comment: Конечно,полно украиноязычных интернет-пользователей,я - один из них.А какой процент, подсчитать трудно.Я встречал цифры от 2-3 до 12-15 процентов. Зайдите на популярный ресурс I.UA, попробуйте оценить сами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кроме языка и диалекта есть ещё понятие варианта языка. Думается, критерии разграничения в этой достаточно огнеопасной области лежат не столько в лингвистической, сколько в политической плоскости. Особенно наглядно это видно на примере немецкого языка. Австрийцы совсем не понимают платтдойч, на коем говорят, скажем, уроженцы Гамбурга, точно так же, как не понимают его и баварцы, говорящие на баварском, и швабы, употребляющие швабский, да и берлинцы со своим берлинским. При этом австрийцы, баварцы и швабы общаются меж собой без малейших трудностей, с берлинцами всем им говорить уже немного не так комфортно, а с гамбуржцами и вовсе беда. Тем не менее баварский, швабский и берлинский, а также платтдойч - *диалекты* немецкого языка, а вот австрийский (как настаивают австрийские германисты) - *вариант* немецкого языка...

Comment: "Бездоказательно. И вообще сильно отдает политической ангажиров. Если так, то откуда тогда в украинском столько полонизмов?"

Вот отсюда и вопрос мой,ведь,если читать, например,"Конституцию" Ф.Орлика и современные ей документы,полонизмов там почти нет, можно сказать,что язык этих документовчуть окрашен в южные тона.Так же, как по стилю и лексическим особенностям мы относим автора "Слова о полку..." к южно-русской школе письменного языка.ВСЕ летописи земель русских писаны по-русски, всё,что можно отнести к литературе - русский язык.Фольклор местами украинский,правда,когда записано-неизвестно.

Comment: И вообще сильно отдает политической ангажированностью

Comment: Само создание украинского языка и все попытки создания на русской земле нерусских государственных образований - чистая политика.

Comment: >Кроме языка и диалекта есть ещё понятие варианта языка


_Спасибо.Такой термин меня удовлетворяет._

Comment: >@Варяг-91, у меня складывается такое ощущение, что написание слов в украинском языке более фонетическое по сравнению с русским.

Возможно,в какой-то степени.Но вот,поездите по Украине,послушайте региональные говоры...

Answer (score 6):

> Хотелось бы все же услышать неусложненный ответ на вопрос, по каким признакам можно считать язык ... полноценным состоявшимся языком

Нет таких признаков. В смысле - неусложненных. Да Вы, видимо, это понимаете, раз ставите вопрос именно о "неусложненныом" ответе. Спорят много и долго, есть целый ряд критериев (см. [Википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%C2%BB) хотя бы), но они не универсальны.

Главными критериями языка по сравнению с диалектом можно считать:
-функционально полноценный;
-имеющий собственный письменный стандарт, независимый от других языков;
-функционирующий в разных сферах письменного и устного общения;
(Там же)

Касательно русского и украинского. Тут сомнений нет. Разделение началось в XIV веке с отходом Киева и всей территории Киевской Руси к Великому княжеству Литовскому (позднее - Речь Посполитая).

> Все славянские языки произошли от древнерусского

Простите, но это абсолютно не соответствует действительности. Посмотрите в любом учебнике.
Очень кратко схема такая. Германославянская общность (гипотетическая) > Балтославянская общность > протославянская общность (гипотетическая) > праславянский язык > западнославянские языки + южновосточнославянскиеязыки > 
южнославянский (древнеболгарский=ЦСЯ) + восточнославянский (древнерусский)

Древнерусский распался на украинский, белорусский и собственно русский.

Comment: to behemothus Трудно согласиться,что разделение произошло таким образом, как Вы считаете.По порядку.Киев уже в XII веке утратил статус столицы,точнее после разгрома 1169 года коалицией князей "Киев пал и уже не поднялся".Андрей Георгиевич, одержавший победу, перенес "стол великокняжеский" во Владимир(на Клязьме),за ним позднее последовал и митрополит,который еще 200 лет именовался Киевским и всея Руси, а "сидел"во Владимире,затем в Москве.Даже после того,как Киев стал провинцией Литвы,затем Польши,он оставался авторитетным центром русской учености,снабжавшим грамотеями всю остальную Русь.

Comment: Что конкретно в моей схеме не так? Она, конечно примитивная, всего там не укажешь. Можно обсудить. 

Только учтите, что знание истории помогает искать, но не предопределят ответы на подобные вопросы. Вопрос о столице вообще не связан с языковыми проблемами подобного рода.

Comment: Если Ломоносов учился в Москве по учебнику, написанному за 150 лет до него униатом Магницким,какой же язык был стандартом для всего тогдашнего Русского мира?Наверное, Вы правы в отношении просторечных говоров(на моей памяти издавались книжечки на вологодском и поморском "языках").Русинский язык,удивительно похожий на русский,(конечно,и на украинский)-неотъемлемое явление современности.А "суржик" и сейчас язык миллионов украинцев.Литературный украинский создан усилиями считанных энтузиастов в течение нескольких десятилетий и внедрен на территории УССР совершенно тоталитарными методами.

Comment: При большом желании и наличии политической воли можно было создать поморский или сибирский язык на основе местных просторечных говоров с помощью терминов, как можно больше удаленных от основы.Как бы то ни было украинский язык состоялся,есть миллионы носителей, он совершенно полноценен(в 20-е годы комиссия по терминам предложила пять тысяч(!)новых слов из немецкого,польского,словацкого,просто придуманных взамен применяемых общерусских слов.)Лексически он все же отличается от русского,но основа,мне кажется, та же.Синтаксически-это один и тот же язык.Десяток польских идиом положение не меняет.

Comment: @Варяг-91, у меня складывается такое ощущение, что написание слов в украинском языке более фонетическое по сравнению с русским. Если это так, то эти два языка все-таки разные и показывают два разных подхода к общей культурной базе.

Comment: to behemothus  В Вашей схеме не так только то, что украинский язык как этнический начал создаваться не ранее конца 18-начала 19 века, до этого была совокупность местечковых наречий с некоторыми общими чертами."Конституция"Ф.Орлика написана по русски(правда, и на латыни).Что-то похожее на украинский литературный язык появляется не ранее начала 19 века.Вот меня и интересует: набитый германизмами полонизмами,просторечными и устаревшими словами и оборотами украинский язык перестал быть русским по сути, основе или нет?

Comment: to behemothus Кроме того, "не так" то, что не "вся Киевская Русь" отошла ВКЛ а затем Речи Посполитой.Северские княжества,псковские,новгородские земли,ростовско-суздальская земля вошли в состав Золотой Орды.Позже были и переделы.

Comment: >как этнический начал создаваться не ранее конца 18-начала 19 века,  

Бездоказательно. И вообще сильно отдает политической ангажированностью. Врочем есть и масса конкретных возражений. Например. Если так, то откуда тогда в украинском столько полонизмов?

Что еще за оборот "язык как этнический"? 

>Северские княжества,псковские,новгородские земли,ростовско-суздальская...

Согласен. Но это и так ясно. Имелась в виду Киевская Русь в исходных границах X-XII веков. 
К вопросу о диалектах это не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score 4):

Все славянские языки произошли от древнерусского. Этот язык занял большущую территорию, поэтому не мог равномерно и одинаково развиваться во всех ещё частях. Попросту не было быстрых и надёжных средств связи, к тому же на каждой из территорий до древнерусского тоже не на пальцах общались, уже были какие-то традиции говорения, которые и были перенесены на древнерусский. После произошел постепенный раздел на разные языки: на русский, белорусский, украинский и т.д. То есть, говоря другими словами, ввиду разных традиций у украинцев, русских и белорусов образовались разные языки.  
Так как древнерусский язык не сохранился, то современные языки нельзя назвать его диалектами, к тому же разница в них на сегодняшний день значительная.  
P.S. Думается мне, что это разделение на языки произошло далеко не 200-300 лет назад, а намного раньше.

Comment: Возможно, со временем я действительно ошибся. Только в 19-20 веках начала расти сознательность украинцев, которые захотели отличаться от русских, но язык за такой маленький промежуток времени не мог так сильно измениться. Эти изменения, возможно, поначалу были обычными наречиями, после чего вылились в целый язык.    
В любом случае сейчас уже нельзя ни белорусский, ни украинский, ни русский называть диалектом, ибо они признаны и чиновниками, и филологами самостоятельными языками.

Comment: "Все славянские языки произошли от древнерусского"... Что-то мне думается,что древнерусский произошел от какого-нибудь вендского или серболужицкого,а вот в отношении "всех славянских" Вы подзагнули. Польский,сдается,разошелся с русским тысячи 2 лет назад, если не более.А традиции у современных украинцев,пожалуй,русские.О том, что их следует звать украинцами они узнали не раньше конца 19 века.Но это совсем другая история,политическая.Меня же интересует лингвистика.Общеизвестно,что баварцы не понимают мекленбуржцев,лексика разная,а язык один.Не та же тут история?

Answer (score 2):

Много правильного, но совсем упущен (церковно-)славянский язык, который выполнял роль основного "носителя" письменности в общерусском пространстве. Благодаря ему, в том числе, осуществлялась горизонтальная  и временнАя связь и обмен знаниями на всем русском пространстве. Кстати, именно на этом языке вначале литераторствовал И.Франко - главный создатель официального украинского языка. Одно замечание Варягу, по современным данным лингвистики, истории и археологии, общеславянский язык сохранялся, как минимум, до 6 века Хр. эры. А на момент создание Древнерусского государства все славянские племена понимали наречия друг друга без толмачей. По поводу очевидных критериев языка, можно добавить - наличие литературы на этом языке. Например, как бы я ни приветствовал в душе сохранение некоего общерусского языка наряду с малороссийскими наречиями, но Т.Г. Шевченко своим Кобзарём поставил точку в вопросе о существовании или нет украинского языка.

Comment: Лишнее это все. 
Тем более сейчас, когда тезис "украинский - это не язык" стал официальным "оружием возмездия" в Крыму и на отколовшейся части Донбасса...

Comment: Я бы РАД с Вами согласиться! Но, к сожалению, есть объективная "от нас" реальность. (Балл я Вам поставил :-) )

Comment: Кстати, не всё ещё потеряно! Можно пойти по пути арабов и частично евреев. А именно: воссоздать некогда общий письменный (и он же сакральный) язык - церковно-славянский. Перевести на него переписку. Остальные языки: русский, украинский, белорусский объявить диалектами. (Кстати, современный русский и так на большее не тянет.) С точки зрения результата: у арабов это работает безотказно, да и такие, как я, перестанут стенать об уничтожении национального языка. С точки зрения технологии: евреи, словаки, те же украинцы и др. доказали, что искусственное (вос-)создание языка - это реальность.

Comment: Если серьёзно, то это на самом деле вариант решения и сегодняшних кровавых проблем, и исторического раздробления большого русского этноса. Нет отдельного языка - нет отдельного этноса.